# Does code location matter in RISC-V code model?

Tags: riscv

I am trying to understand RISC-V code models.
I have read:

- blog post [All Aboard, Part 4: The RISC-V Code Models](https://www.sifive.com/blog/all-aboard-part-4-risc-v-code-models),
- [GCC RISC-V options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/RISC-V-Options.html), and
- [SiFive: RISC-V Large Code Model Software Workaround](https://sifive.cdn.prismic.io/sifive%2F15d1d90e-f60e-42a2-b6bf-c805c6c73b0d_riscv-large-code-model-workaround.pdf)

I think I have got most concepts, but following descriptions confuses me:

- In the blog post:

> What does -mcmodel=medlow mean?
>
> ... This selects the medium-low code model, which means program and its statically defined symbols must lie within a single 2 GiB address range ....

- In the GCC document:

> -mcmodel=medlow
>
> ... The program and its statically defined symbols must lie within a single 2 GiB address range

- In SiFive pdf

> Both code models restrict the generated code to be 2GiB or less

I know that global symbols should reside between +/- 2GB (since `lui` loads upper 20-bit of U-immediate into rd, and `ld` handles the lower signed 12-bit offset), but why the location of code matters?
If the emitted instructions are `lui`/`ld`, as long as the referenced symbol lies between +/- 2GB, would it matter if I put my function outside the 2GB range?